# How to use Mockery for unit testing in PHP 7.2 and mocking Eloquent queries

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5.5, mockery

I want to create a set of unit tests for an existing production system, that will be executed locally, triggered by a pre-commit hook.

As a requirement the tests have to run 3-4 secs max.

By definition, the unit tests should call methods in isolation. However, the system is heavily DB dependent so I want to be able to mock the database calls.

The application is running PHP 7.2, Laravel 5.5.4.

I have been trying to use Mockery with no success. Here is a simple example of what I had been trying to do:

```
public function testExample()
{
    // Create a new user
    $newUser = new User();
    $newUser->id = 1;

    // Mock the User
    $mockedUser = Mockery::mock(User::class);
    // Mock the Builder
    $mockedBuilder = Mockery::mock(Builder::class);
    $this->app->instance(Builder::class, $mockedBuilder);
    $this->app->instance(User::class, $mockedUser);
    // Set the expectations
    $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('first')->once()->andReturn($newUser);
    $mockedUser->shouldReceive('where')
        ->with('id', 5)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($mockedBuilder);

    $this->assertEquals($newUser->id, User::where('id', 5)->first()->id);
}
```

However, since "where" is actually a static call to Builder, it doesn't work.
Is there any way to achieve it? I though of mocking the DB facade (or PDO) but it seems too .. rough. Any better ideas?

Comment: Which builder class are you mocking?   where should not be a static call to Builder since it is using Laravel's facades.

Comment: I tried using both `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, neither of them work.

Comment: This is where xdebug would be extremely useful, to see where the calls are ending up.  Hard to tell you without attempting it mysel.f

Comment: Xdebug shows I'm entering the 'where' method of 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder'.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something like that. had you any luck? Would you, please, clarify how you resolved the issue or at least give any tip? Real thanks.